# Discord.js push slash commands

Tags: discord.js

I recently started writing Discordbots and just can't seem to get anywhere pushing the slash commands. I already have a handler file (pushSlash.js) but for some reason the commands are never loaded or I get an error in the console (mostly simply this: chalk.blue is not a function). My bot also doesn't get the badge that it supports slash commands.

Can anyone help me further?

Here is my code (pushSlash.js):

```
module.exports = (client) => {
    const fs = require('fs');

    const { PermissionsBitField } = require('discord.js');
    const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
    const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');

    const AsciiTable = require('ascii-table');
    const table = new AsciiTable().setHeading('Slash Commands', 'Stats').setBorder('|', '=', "0", "0");

    const TOKEN = process.env.BOT_TOKEN;
    const CLIENT_ID = process.env.CLIENT_ID;

    const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(TOKEN);

    import( 'chalk').then(chalk => {
        const slashCommands = []; 

        fs.readdirSync('/home/container/src/slashCommands/').forEach(async dir => {
            const files = fs.readdirSync(`/home/container/src/slashCommands/${dir}/`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

            for(const file of files) {
                const slashCommand = require(`/home/container/src/slashCommands/${dir}/${file}`);
                slashCommands.push({
                    name: slashCommand.name,
                    description: slashCommand.description,
                    options: slashCommand.options ? slashCommand.options : null,
                    default_permission: slashCommand.default_permission ? slashCommand.default_permission : null,
                    default_member_permissions: slashCommand.default_member_permissions ? PermissionsBitField.resolve(slashCommand.default_member_permissions).toString() : null
                });

                if(slashCommand.name) {
                    client.slashCommands.set(slashCommand.name, slashCommand);
                    table.addRow(file.split('.js')[0], '✅');
                } else {
                    table.addRow(file.split('.js')[0], '⛔');
                }
            }

        });
        console.log(chalk.blue(table.toString()));

        (async () => {
            try {
                await rest.put(
                    process.env.GUILD_ID ?
                    Routes.applicationGuildCommands(CLIENT_ID, process.env.GUILD_ID) :
                    Routes.applicationCommands(CLIENT_ID), 
                    { body: slashCommands }
                );
                console.log(chalk.green('Successfully registered application commands.'));
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        })();
    });
};
```

I've already tried everything possible, but since I'm relatively new to discord.js, I don't know that much yet either.
Actually everything should work and exactly 2 different commands should be loaded, but I only get error messages or the handler was loaded on console but nothing is displayed on Discord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first download `chalk@4.1.2` with

```js
npm install chalk@4.1.2
```

and import [chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk) normally.

```js
const chalk = require('chalk')
```

There your code modified version:

```js
module.exports = (client) => {
    const fs = require('fs');

    const { PermissionsBitField } = require('discord.js');
    const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
    const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');



    const AsciiTable = require('ascii-table');
    const table = new AsciiTable().setHeading('Slash Commands', 'Stats').setBorder('|', '=', "0", "0");

    const TOKEN = process.env.BOT_TOKEN;
    const CLIENT_ID = process.env.CLIENT_ID;

    const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(TOKEN);

    // Imported chalk normally
    const chalk = require('chalk')
    
    // removed `import( 'chalk').then(chalk => {})`
    const slashCommands = []; 

    fs.readdirSync('/home/container/src/slashCommands/').forEach(async dir => {
        const files = fs.readdirSync(`/home/container/src/slashCommands/${dir}/`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

        for(const file of files) {
            const slashCommand = require(`/home/container/src/slashCommands/${dir}/${file}`);
            slashCommands.push({
                name: slashCommand.name,
                description: slashCommand.description,
                options: slashCommand.options ? slashCommand.options : null,
                default_permission: slashCommand.default_permission ? slashCommand.default_permission : null,
                default_member_permissions: slashCommand.default_member_permissions ? PermissionsBitField.resolve(slashCommand.default_member_permissions).toString() : null
            });

            if(slashCommand.name) {
                client.slashCommands.set(slashCommand.name, slashCommand);
                table.addRow(file.split('.js')[0], '✅');
            } else {
                table.addRow(file.split('.js')[0], '⛔');
            }
        }

    });

    console.log(chalk.blue(table.toString()));

    (async () => {
        try {
            await rest.put(
                process.env.GUILD_ID ?
                Routes.applicationGuildCommands(CLIENT_ID, process.env.GUILD_ID) :
                Routes.applicationCommands(CLIENT_ID), 
                { body: slashCommands }
            );
            console.log(chalk.green('Successfully registered application commands.'));
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    })();
};
```